# How to add a falloff to noise textures?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to generate a custom landscape with geometry nodes on a particular shape(part of another landscape) while keeping the perimeter area so that I can merge them seamlessy.
However I can't seem to be able to do so using the edge neighbours node.
Here is my setup:
[image]
And this is the output:
[image]

Instead of there being a soft fallof there is just an abrupt angle which doesn't blend well with the original landscape.
Does anyone know how to make a more gentle falloff?
Thanks for the help!
SG

Comment: Please provide blend file to make it as easy as possible for us, who help you for free in our spare time. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the falloff is by scaling the displacement down with the distance from an empty object. The screenshot below shows how I did that. I prefer to use an empty object to be able to move it around in 3D space and see the effect of that. You can remove it from the setup and input the coordinates of the center point of the falloff manually.

[image: Terrain]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!